# uninitialized constant NumberHelper when doing include

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am following Lynda tutorial on Rspec. I was solving one of the challenges but something seems not to be working. 
My file structure is:

food_finder/lib/support/number_helper.rb
food_finder/spec/support/number_helper_spec.rb

My number_helper.rb looks like:

```
module NumberHelper

     def number_to_currency(number, options={})
         #some_code  
     end
end
```

and number_helper_spec.rb is:

```
 describe 'NumberHelper' do

    include NumberHelper

    describe '#number_to_currency' do
       #some_test_code
    end

  end
```

on executing form food_finder directory:

```
rspec spec/support/number_helper_spec.rb
```

I get error:

> in `block in ': uninitialized constant NumberHelper
>   (NameError)

Comment: Does it work if you remove the line `include NumberHelper`?

Comment: gives " undefined method `number_to_currency' " error. Obviously?

Comment: Did you add `require 'rails_helper'` on top of the spec file? Does it help if you add `require 'support/number_helper'` on top of the spec file? (Did you know that `number_to_currency` is already a built-in Rails helper?)

Comment: yeah adding " require 'support/number_helper' " does the trick. But it is suppose to work without that, right? Turns out I never ran "rspec --init" so there was no rail_helper. Thanks zwippie!

Answer (score 0):

Your code was fine. The module should be loaded with `include NumberHelper`, not `require 'support/number_helper'`. The problem came from not running `rspec --init` from the app's root, so none of the configuration in spec_helper.rb got loaded.

Regarding the comments mentioning Rails' `number_to_currency` method, the module being loaded in this exercise is modeled after the Rails version, but is self-contained:

**number_helper.rb**

```
# This module illustrates how additional functionality can be
# included (or "mixed-in") to a class and then reused.
# Borrows heavily from Ruby on Rails' number_to_currency method.
module NumberHelper

  def number_to_currency(number, options={})
    unit      = options[:unit]      || '$'
    precision = options[:precision] || 2
    delimiter = options[:delimiter] || ','
    separator = options[:separator] || '.'
...
```